# Angular and Go on heroku

Tags: angularjs, heroku, go, procfile

I am trying to put my app on Heroku. I am using angular on the front-end and Go on the backend.

I followed this tutorial http://mmcgrana.github.io/2012/09/getting-started-with-go-on-heroku.html

However, when I go to the domain of my heroku app, I get the directory of my app (everything in the git). When I navigate to the /app folder, (where my angular app lives) it shows the app.

I don't want my app to be at

```
foobar.herokuapp.com/app/#/
```

I want it to be at

```
foobar.herokuapp.com
```

A simplified version of my app directory is:

```
foobar
 - /app
 - /server/server.go
 - .godir             // contains "app"
 - Procfile           // contains "web: server"
```

I ran "go get" from inside my /server folder

These work:

```
$ PORT=5000 demoapp

$ curl -i http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

Here is my simple server.go

```
package main

import (
"github.com/gorilla/handlers"
"log"
"net/http"
"os"
)

func main() {
log.Println("Starting Server")
http.Handle("/", logHandler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("../app/"))))

log.Println("Listening...")
panic(http.ListenAndServe(":"+os.Getenv("PORT"), nil))
}

func logHandler(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
return handlers.LoggingHandler(os.Stdout, h)
```

}

Comment: Can you link to the code?  Need to see how the routing is done in your server.

Comment: Sure. That is my server.

Comment: I am just using it for a landing page right now so I removed the server directory and it works with my server.go file under foobar.

Answer (score 1):

Changing your FileServer directory from `"../app/"` to `"app/"` (relative) or `"/app/app/"` (absolute) should solve the issue.

```
http.Handle("/", logHandler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("app/"))))
```

Your project root is the work folder when Heroku executes the Procfile command. It has the absolute path `/app` which is why `../app` brings you back to your project root.

Although your `server.go` is stored in the `./server` subfolder it is still compiled into the project root with `package main`.